# Apollo GraphQL: How to Set Up Secure Websockets?

Tags: websocket, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm setting up my dev system to use `https`, and Chrome is complaining about my websocket not begin secure:

> VM4965:161 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.io/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket
>   endpoint 'ws://mywebsite.io:4000/subscriptions'. This request has
>   been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

Here's my current server-side setup for WS, based on the Apollo docs:

```
const localHostString = 'mywebsite.io'; 
const pubsub = new PubSub();

// additional context you use for your resolvers, if any
const context = {connectors: connectors};

//SET UP APOLLO QUERY / MUTATIONS / PUBSUB
//start a graphql server with Express handling a possible Meteor current user
createApolloServer({
    schema,
    context
});

const METEOR_PORT = 3000;
const GRAPHQL_PORT = 4000;
const server = express();

server.use('*', cors({ origin: `https://${localHostString}:${METEOR_PORT}` }));

server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    schema,
    context
}));

server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql',
    subscriptionsEndpoint: `ws://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/subscriptions`
}));

// Wrap the Express server
const ws = createServer(server);
ws.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`);
    console.log(`GraphiQL available at http://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/graphiql`);
    // Set up the WebSocket for handling GraphQL subscriptions
    new SubscriptionServer({
        execute,
        subscribe,
        schema
    }, {
        server: ws,
        path: '/subscriptions',
    });
});
```

How can I update this so as to use WSS rather than WS websockets?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: you had any luck with the problem?

Comment: Yes. At the time I solved it, for development purposes only, by using ngrok. I set up a separate ngrok URL for https and for wss.  Ngrok handled calls to those secure URLs by serving data from my local dev system, which was still on http and ws.   HOWEVER when I tried that recently with my latest server/client code and with the latest Apollo libraries, I was seeing errors in Firefox, with some ngrok packages not loading.  Currently I'm putting my app on Galaxy. For dev purposes using https/wss, I'll probably have to install an SSL certificate on my local dev system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're doing

```
subscriptionsEndpoint: `ws://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/subscriptions
```

Maybe instead, change `ws` to `wss`. ie:

```
subscriptionsEndpoint: `wss://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/subscriptions
```